# Mathematical intro to Turing machines

Tags: computability

Is there a good mathematically rigorous introduction to computability theory based on Turing machines? I have looked at some CS books but found them quite unsatisfying for a mathematician (too wordy in the chatty parts, too vague when it comes to details, along the lines of "existence of a universal machine: why, isn't that clear?").
I am (I would hope) "mathematically mature" and I know some basic recursion theory.

Comment: Seems like a good candidate to merge with [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1076017/29335)